# Can't ping VM after live migrate proxmox 4.2

Tags: migrate, proxmox

I set up DRBD between 2 computers in a cluster. In the Proxmox GUI online, I migrated the VM to the other node while running a continuous ping on the VM. I was getting 1ms replies, but when the migration completed my pings timed out. I tried migrating back to the original node but I never got a reply back during the ping.  After shutting down and restarting the VM, I can ping again.

How can I successfully live migrate the VM without losing connectivity?

Comment: Does Proxmox finish the migration task without any errors?

Comment: Yes it finishes with no errors. I tried again today and the pings continued successfully during and after migration. Not sure why it's glitching but definitely need to find out if you have any ideas

Comment: Has the live migration ever worked in your setup?

Comment: Yes, today it worked successfully several times.

Comment: Ahh damn, yeah sorry I read that wrong. Live migrations during updates can cause this, meaning one host is already updated with newer packages. Furthermore I would search the system logs for any hints.

Comment: oh okay that would make sense. I did run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade on both computers since then, thank you!

Comment: So it happened again. Migrated it to the other node and couldn't ping. Reset the node and brought it up again then migrated and the ping went through. No problems now, there's definitely still something wrong because it they were both updated at the same time before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116572/discussion-between-michael-and-kirrmann).